# Aiogram код перестал обрабатывать команды?

Tags: python, aiogram

пишу код на aiogram и сталкиваюсь с тем что вставляя очередной обработчик в свой код бот его перестает обрабатывать ошибок в данным обработчике который я вставил быть не может проверял на другом токене с небольшим написаном скриптом на 75 строк и там он работает но когда вставляю тот же самый обработчик в скрипт на 180строк он прекращает работать

Comment: значит что-то перекрывает этот хендлер, покажите его

Answer (score 0):

Обычно такие проблемы возникают, когда при написании обработчиков не учитываются все возможные исходы выполнения кода и не используются стандартные конструкции для обработки ошибок.

Для устранения проблем с обработкой ошибок вам может помочь использование конструкции try-except вокруг вызова функций, которые могут вызвать исключения, и отправка информации об исключениях через логирование или сообщения в чат бота.

Пример:
import logging

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start_handler(message: types.Message):
    try:
        # тут код
    except Exception as e:
        logging.exception(e)
        await message.reply('Произошла ошибка при выполнении команды')
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Почему публикация ответов созданных GPT и ChatGPT недопустима?](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)